# IKM C++ assessment asks about std::unordered_set, part #1

Tags: c++, stl

Recently I had to do an IKM C++ assessment to qualify for a job. Some of the questions seemed strange to me, so I'll be doing a few posts here to discuss.

The first one is related to use of std::unordered_set. From what I remember it went something like:

> A programmer is using a struct to contain some data. The struct must be stored in a std::unordered_set. True or false: The structure has to overload the method operator==() in order for the structure to be supported by std::unordered_set?

I wrote a test program to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>

struct ikm_test_struct {

   size_t m1;
   
   std::size_t operator()(ikm_test_struct const& s) const noexcept;  
   
   constexpr bool operator==(const ikm_test_struct &rhs) const;
};

// Method operator() must return a size_t so use its limits in our distribution.

std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(
   std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::min(),
   std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()
);

std::size_t ikm_test_struct::operator()(ikm_test_struct const& s) const noexcept {

   // Seed a random number generator using the value in the parameter struct.
    
   std::mt19937 gen(s.m1);
    
   // Exercise the random number generator so that it is well away from any less random starting values.

   for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) distrib(gen);
    
   // Generate a random number in the required range.
    
   return distrib(gen);
}

constexpr bool ikm_test_struct::operator==(const ikm_test_struct &rhs) const {
   return m1 == rhs.m1;
}

typedef std::unordered_set<ikm_test_struct, ikm_test_struct> ikm_test_unordered_set;

int main()
{      
   ikm_test_unordered_set x;
   
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
   
      ikm_test_struct y;
      y.m1 = i;
      
      x.insert(y);
   }
   
   size_t j = 0;
   for (const auto& k: x) {
      std::cout << "x[" << j << "] = " << k.m1 << std::endl;
      ++j;
   }
}
```

So it is possible to write a structure that implements operator==() and is then used in a std::unordered_set. Given this demonstration how should we answer the original question:

1. The demo code proves that it is possible to do this but the question says "has to overload the method operator==()". There are other ways to implement an equality test. Like creating a separate class or struct and using that class as the third parameter on the std::unordered_set template. So do you answer the question yes because it is possible or no because you don't have to do it that way?
2. The question says "has to overload". But the demo code implements operator==() only once, so there is no "overloading" of this method. If there is no overloading should the question be answered false? That seems to miss the point of asking the question to test your C++ knowledge.
3. The question says "in order for the structure to be supported". "Supported" is kind of ambiguous. Supported how, with what specialization of std::unordered_set, with what other helper classes?

Given the above it seems that the question is one that has no correct answer. Therefore, it is stupid to include it in a test that is supposed to evaluate someones C++ skills.

What do you think?

Comment: The questions (how does on reply to the interview question?) seem to have no bearing on what you expect to gain from a **review** of this code.  As such, Code Review is not the place to be asking those; perhaps it would be on-topic on [so]?

Comment: @TobySpeight I suspect it would be considered too broad on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Defining an `operator==` for your own type *is* overloading.  The overload set includes all the built-in signatures.

Based on how you worded it, I agree with (1).  It is not true that you *must* define `operator==` for that struct in order to use it with `std::unordered_set`.  You can use the template argument, or you can cause the default predicate to work in other ways especially in newer versions of C++ (e.g. default the spaceship operator).

As for the example, doesn't it also need to specialize `std::hash` in order for it to work?  `std::unordered_set<ikm_test_struct, ikm_test_struct>` doesn't make sense.

If this test is going to be *read* by other prospective team members, then essaying what you thought is going to communicate to them that you (1) know your stuff; and (2) will be likely to apply the same skill to interpreting requirements.  Finish by correcting the sloppy nomenclature, linking to cppreference and/or a copy of the Standard, and reviewing the code of the sample (with citations to the Standard Guidelines).

If you're passed on as "overqualified", you'll be glad in the long run.

If it's a multiple-choice computer-based thing that just reports the score, that can be a real pain.  I recall encountering one where the expected results were sometimes just plain wrong, or out of date, or the question was worded poorly.  You should contact the people who made the test.

Comment: +1 I agree though I find it's missing the point why things can blow up, thought it's just a nitpick as OP seem to get it. One should make sure `unordered_set` uses appropriate comparator, that is the basis. **By default, default (sic!) operator will match because of implicit conversions**... this is crucial. Correct code should alleviate that, either by providing a better (possibly exact) match, or explicit template param. I think this is a multi-level question to gauge level of candidate it can't really be cast down to correct-wrong.

Comment: @luk32 I don't follow what you are saying.  The default template argument to `unordered_set` is `equal_to<Key>` (not to be confused with `equal_to<>`) which looks for `==` between two values of type `Key`; that itself may be satisfied by rewrite rules, implicit conversions, or automatic generation.

Comment: No wonder. I think, I've missed the definition of `opeartor==` in the code and thought the it would compile, but be incorrect, because of a match for `operator==(unsigned int, unsigned int)` due to implicit conversion (which gives back a random number). But it was given and appears sensible, this makes my comment moot. I'm sorry.

Comment: @luk32 I think you're confusing the `operator()` that takes a second test_struct with an implicit conversion operator `operator size_t()` ?

Comment: Embarrassingly true. I confused conversion operator to `size_t` with `operator()` returning `size_t`. Double dipped on silliness. Good to be humbled. Thanks again.

Comment: I appreciate JDługosz's comment about just defining the operator== being overloading. I've never thought of it that way. But thinking again that is the only way everything would work.

About the hash: Doing std::unordered_set<ikm_test_struct, ikm_test_struct> says an instance of the struct itself provides the hash function by implementing operator(). I added that because there was another similar question for overloading that operator.

It was a multiple-choice computer-based thing that just reports the score. But I did well enough to get a ZOOM interview follow up. And that got me hired.

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JDługosz and luk32 for comment and discussion.

To answer the question I should provide more context. The full question went something like:

> A programmer is using a struct to contain some data. The struct must be stored in a std::unordered_set. Which of the following is true:
>
> a.) The structure has to overload operator==() in order for this type to be supported by std::unordered_set
>
> b.) The structure has to overload operator<() so that the elements can be stored in the proper place within the collection
>
> c.) The structure has to provide a default constructor
>
> d.) The structure has to overload operator() so that elements can be found in collection
>
> e.) The structure has to create a std::hash specialization

The rules of the assessment say that one or more must be true. So:

Based on comment and discussion. a.) and d.) are false if you think "It is not true that you MUST define...". And true if you think "That is one possibility".

b.) is false since std::unordered_set is based on hashing not on sorting the collection.

If a.) and b.) are true then c.) must be true. Since if the operator==() and operator() are used std::unordered_set must create one or more default instances to call them on.

If d.) is true then the hash function is provided by operator(). If that is the case then no std::hash specialization is needed and e.) is false. Even is d.) is false then there are other ways of doing the hash.

So if I take the "It is not true that you MUST define..." approach, then none of these are true. But the rules of the assessment say that at least one must be true. Most obvious candidates seem to be a.) and d.). If a.) and d.) are true then c is true and e is false.

So my best guess is that I should have answered a.), c.) and d.). And that is what I believe the assessment was looking for.

But my guess is based on choosing what I think is the most "obvious", not on something that I am certain about. The question therefore remains one with no real correct answer.